# how to bind AltGr to Control_L in linux virtual console?

Tags: linux, keyboard, console, keymap

I want that my right alt <kbd>AltGr</kbd> behaves as my left control <kbd>Control_L</kbd> in linux virtual console.

I use the `showkey` utility and found out that pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> generates keycode `100`. So I wrote a rebind.map file with this line:

```
keycode 100 = Control
```

And then I've loaded this configuration with `loadkeys $(readlink -f rebind.map)`

So If I press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> it should produce the same result as <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. And it does, on the first press. On the second press, the keyboard becomes unusable.

How do I correctly bind my <kbd>AltGr</kbd> to behave as <kbd>Control_L</kbd> in linux virtual console?

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you on?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 I'm on arch linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution. I don't know exactly why it works though. 
The secret is to add `keymaps 0-15` above the `keycode 100 = Control` line, like so:

```
keymaps 0-15
keycode 100 = Control
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean unusable as in Control seems to be pressed constantly? I just tried the same thing and had the same problem. My workaround was saving the current keymap with `dumpkeys` and extracting the line for the keycode I wanted to change, which was

```
keycode 56 = Alt ... (Alt repeated a total of 128 times)
```

So I changed that line to be

```
keycode 56 = Control ... (Control repeated a total of 128 times)
```

and loaded the file with that line in it via `loadkeys` and it seems to work now.